# converting class to hooks getting messages

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

i'm new to react hooks, here i have been converting my project to hooks from classes, i'm getting this kind of  message 'Error: Server error
at build_error (actions.js:57)
at eval (actions.js:83)' and 'GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/kamera/undefined 404 (Not Found)'

those errors come when i'm changing class to hooks (everything is set correcly using useState and useEffect), any idea ?

class:

```js
  initializeCollapses() {
    const data = this.props[this.props.action];
    let collapseStates = this.state.collapseStates;
    if (!data || data.length < 1) {
      return;
    }
    data.map((el) => {
      collapseStates["" + el.name + el.identifier] = false;
      return;
    });
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      collapseStates: collapseStates,
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getItems[this.props.action](this.state.actionArgs).then(() => {
      this.initializeCollapses();
    });
  }
```

Hooks:

```js
 const initializeCollapses = () => {
    const data = [action];
    if (!data || data.length < 1) {
      return;
    }
    data.map((el) => {
      collapseStates["" + el.name + el.identifier] = false;
      return;
    });
    setCollapseStates(collapseStates);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getItems[action](actionArgs).then(() => {
      initializeCollapses();
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: Can you provide how you extracted the [action]? in hooks file where are you destructuring it?

Comment: Need the getItems' implementation to find where things are going wrong.

Comment: the code i wrote in question is inside this : function ConnectedSelectionList({
  action,
  actionArgs,
  onUpdateClick,
  onDeleteClick,
  onDetailsClick,
  classes,
  currentItem,
  getItems,
  changeActiveItem,
  unselectActiveItem,
}) {

Comment: Is this mapDispatchToProps used in hooks implementation?

Comment: at the end of code : i'm exporting export const MSelectionList = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ConnectedSelectionList);

Comment: should i convert that 'mapDispatchToProps' to hooks somehow ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  initializeCollapses() {
    const data = this.props[this.props.action];
    let collapseStates = this.state.collapseStates;
    if (!data || data.length < 1) {
      return;
    }
    data.map((el) => {
      collapseStates["" + el.name + el.identifier] = false;
      return;
    });
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      collapseStates: collapseStates,
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getItems[this.props.action](this.state.actionArgs).then(() => {
      this.initializeCollapses();
    });
  }

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return { 
      getItems: {
         analysers: (site) => dispatch(getAnalysers(site)),
         platforms: (site) => dispatch(getPlatforms(site)),
         brokers: (site) => dispatch(getBrokers(site)),
         cameras: (site) => dispatch(getCameras(site)),
         sites: (site) => dispatch(getSites())
  },
 };
};
```

The above class implementation in hooks would roughly be as below

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import  getItems from "./store/actions";
   or
import { cameras, sites, platform, brokers } from "./store/actions";

const actionArgs = useSelector(state => state.actionArgs); // In place of mapStateToProps
const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getItems.cameras(actionArgs)) or dispatch(cameras(actionArgs)) //If destructured

  }, []);
```

I have provided an understandable example with whatever data you provided. [Refer this](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/using-redux-with-react-hooks) for a completely different approach or [this one](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-replacing-mapdispatchtoprops-with-the-usedispatch-hook) for the same mapDispatchToProps approach.

[Good to refer](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks)

**Example**:

```
import React, {useReducer} from 'react';

const init = 0;

const myReducer = (state, action) => {
     switch(action.type){
         case 'increment':
             return state + 1 // complex actions are kept in seperate files for better organised, clean code
         case 'decrement':
             return state - 1
         case 'reset':   // action types as well are kept as selectors
             return init
         default:
             return state
     }
};

function ReducerExample(){

    const [count, dispatch] = useReducer(myReducer, init)

    const add = () => {
        dispatch({type: 'increment'})
    }

    const sub = () => {
        dispatch({type: 'decrement'})
    }

    const reset = () => {
        dispatch({type: 'reset'})
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h4>Count: {count}</h4>
            <button onClick={add} style={{margin: '10px'}}>Increment</button>
            <button onClick={sub}>Decrement</button>
            <button onClick={reset} style={{margin: '10px'}}>Reset</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ReducerExample;
```

Comment: i have not changed redux to hooks yet could you provide solution with this connect? i'm first trying to change classes to hooks and use connect(later on change it to hooks also)

Comment: Refer this project https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/03/02/react-hooks-redux-user-registration-and-login-tutorial-example

Comment: connect should work with hooks and also classes ?

Comment: just need to make this work inside useEffect : componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getItems[this.props.action](this.state.actionArgs).then(() => {
      this.initializeCollapses();
    });
  }

Comment: No need. Let me add a simple, easy to understand example.

Comment: inside mapdispatchtoprops i have also:   unselectItem: {
      cameras: (site, id) => dispatch(clearCameraData(site, id)),
      brokers: (site, id) => dispatch(clearBrokerData(site, id)),
      platforms: (site, id) => dispatch(clearPlatformData(site, id)),
      analysers: (site, id) => dispatch(clearAnalyserData(site, id)),
      sites: (site, id) => dispatch(clearSiteData(site, id)),
    }, so if i want to change mapdispatchtoprops into hooks, how would it be ?